# How to get triangles for AABB verts?

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, webgl

I am trying to render cubes to represent AABB's. In order to do this I need the vertices of the cube and the 'cells', or triangles. I have AABB structures that look like `[vec3Min, vec3Max]`. I am able to get the 
8 vertices for the cube using the following

```
export function vertsFromAABB(aabb){
  const min = aabb[0];
  const max = aabb[1];

  return [
    // min Y axis verts
    min,
    [max[0],min[1],min[2]],
    [max[0],min[1],max[2]],
    [min[1],min[1],max[2]],

    // max Y axis verts
    max,
    [min[0],max[1],max[2]],
    [min[0],max[1],min[0]],
    [max[0],max[1],min[0]]
  ];
}
```

I now need to get the triangle indexes from this set of vertices. The cells should be an array of vertex indicies eg `[[0,1,2],[1,2,3], ...]`

**EDIT UPDATE**

I have made the fixes to the last 2 verts that was suggested in the comments. I have a function inprogress for the cells that looks like

```
export function cellsFromAABBVerts(aabbVerts){
  return [
    // Top quad triangles
    [0,1,2],
    [1,2,3],

    // Side?
    [2,3,4],
    [3,4,5],

    // Bottom quad triangles
    [4,5,6],
    [5,6,7],
  ];
}
```

Comment: Where are you having troubles? It seems you know how to generate the indices. Btw, your last two vertices are wrong (they have x-coordinates where they should have z-coordinates).

Comment: thanks @NicoSchertler I need help with the sequence of the indices i'm having a hard time mentally visualizing the pairs. Also a spot check is helpful as you already caught an issue with the verts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you visualize your cuboid, like this:

[image: Visualization]

then it is pretty straight-forward to derive the triangle indices:

```
[
    [ 0, 1, 2 ],
    [ 0, 2, 3 ],
    [ 6, 5, 4 ],
    [ 6, 4, 7 ],
    [ 1, 7, 4 ],
    [ 1, 4, 2 ],
    [ 0, 3, 5 ],
    [ 0, 5, 6 ],
    [ 0, 6, 7 ],
    [ 0, 7, 1 ],
    [ 2, 4, 5 ],
    [ 2, 5, 3 ]
]
```